# How to change to datetime format date with dashes?

Tags: python, pandas, string, datetime

I have a date in format `2022-12-16T16-48-47"` and I would like to change it to `datetime` using function `pd.to_datetime`.

My first idea was to create split the string to have it in more readable way:

```
string = "2022-12-16T16-48-47"
date, hour = string.split("T")
string = date + " " + hour
string
```

And now to use:

```
import pandas as pd
pd.to_datetime(string, format = "%Y-%M-%D %h-%m-%S")
```

But I have error:

```
ValueError: 'D' is a bad directive in format '%Y-%M-%D %h-%m-%S'
```

Do you know how it should be done properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Y`, `m`, `d` and `H`, `M`, `S` instead:

```
>>> pd.to_datetime(string, format = "%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")
Timestamp('2022-12-16 16:48:47')
>>>
```

You should check out the [`strftime` format codes documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes) for better understanding.